# No dll file in mongodb php driver

Tags: php, mongodb

I have downloaded mongodb php driver from https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo.
When I extracted the files I couldn't find the php_mongodb.dll file.

In every tutorial it is said to copy that file. And download the from where I have downloaded.

Still I don't know what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 64-bit machine. And I was trying this file before "php_mongodb-1.4.0-7.1-ts-vc14-x64" which was not supported.

But when I tried this driver "php_mongodb-1.4.2-7.1-ts-vc14-x86" it was accepted.
I downloaded them from here https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb.

I don't why and how, but that worked. I will keep that in mind for future.

Answer (score 0):

[windows mongo list](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mongo/)

You can see all of Windows's mongodb dll
https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mongo/

Comment: still getting this error "Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongo.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 in Unknown on line 0" and they said "To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini"

Comment: give me your php.ini

Comment: Now, I have solved it. I have 64-bit machine, still x64 version of driver was not supported, when i tried with x86 version driver , php.ini  accepted it. And Really Thank you for support.